# API for number of processed emails in Mailgun

Tags: mailgun

A Free Plan Mailgun account is allowed to send 10,000 emails per month. I wonder if there is a way to see how many emails have been sent and received through the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're looking for is the [stats API](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-stats.html#stats)

You could use this to determine how close you are to your monthly totals